# CSV file console logging is undefined - JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to `console.log` a column from a `.csv` file and it is undefined:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("./data.csv", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    const lines = data.split("\n");
    console.log("MID        Merchant");
    for (const line of lines) {
        const columns = line.split(",");
        console.log(columns[0] + "        " + columns[1]);
    }
});
```

Screenshot of the code and data.csv:

[image]

Comment: well, it looks like your file ends with a blank new line

Comment: Can you share your data.csv too?

Comment: Hi tada, it looks like you're a new user. Could you add the Nodejs and FS tags to your post, and give some more information re. what you expect to be output? It will help get you better answers.

Comment: @Akif I've added the data.csv

Comment: i think you have an empty last line in the csv

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As others mentioned in the comments, you have an empty line at the end of your file. You need to check before splitting the line like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('./data.csv', 'utf8' , (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  const lines = data.split('\n') 
  console.log('MID        Merchant')
  for(const line of lines) {

    if (line.includes(',')) { // Check it!
      const columns = line.split(',')
            
      console.log(columns[0]+ '        ' +columns[1])      
    }
    
  }
})
```